# set default values in spring boot configurations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the below scenario. I want to set default values when the key is not available in the application.yml file. i see null always. Please see the below code. If you look at the below code, the element label1 is missing from ios in application.yml file and i am using @value annotation to set the default value. If you look at the TileConfig.java below, i am setting default value as "its android Label" but i always get this as null. Please help me to resolve this. Thanks !

#### application.yml:

```
tile:
  responseConfig:
    android:
      label1: 'label1'
      actionSwitch:
        target: 'someurl'
        method: 'PUT'
        cin: '1'
      actionLink:
        target: 'target'
        data:
          EXTRA_UUID: '{accountId}'
    ios:
      actionSwitch:
        target: 'someUrl'
        method: 'PUT'
        cin: '1'
      actionLink:
        target: 'target'
        data:
          EXTRA_UUID: '{accountId}'
```

#### TileConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "tile.responseConfig")
public class TileConfig {
    
    @Value("${tile.responseConfig.android.label1:its a Label}")
    private String label1;

    private Action actionSwitch;
    private Action actionLink;
    private Action actionSwitchForCard;
    private Action actionLinkForCard;

    public String getLabel1() {
        return label1;
    }

    public void setLabel1(String label1) {
        this.label1 = label1;
    }
```

Comment: Your annotation is looking at android.label1 in the question, I am assuming its typo & you meant ios.label1. Do you get value injected in your field if you put the value in yml file ? I am just wondering if something is wrong with your config & setup for spring to inject.

Comment: You are using `@ConfigurationProperties` in a wrong way. Remove the `@Value` and just set a default in the code. Either use `@ConfigurationProperties` or `@Value` not both.